# Express REST API fails when parsing a payload?

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I am new to NodeJS + Express development.  I want to build a REST API that can receive JSON data via POST.  I was able to build the API in Express and receive a json payload from a transmission from the postman software.  But when I try to simulate the same behaviour with javascript's `fetch()` function from a web browser, my express rest api crashes with the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parse (/home/johncomputer/projects/tt/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:89:19)
    at /home/johncomputer/projects/tt/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:121:18
    at invokeCallback (/home/johncomputer/projects/tt/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:224:16)
    at done (/home/johncomputer/projects/tt/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:213:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/home/johncomputer/projects/tt/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:273:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:215:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1184:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
```

I only have this one file called `src/app.js` in my express project:

```
const express = require('express')
const port = process.env.PORT
var cors = require('cors')

const app = express()

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())

router = express.Router()

router.post('/users', async (req, res) => {
    try {
            console.log("+++++++++++")
            console.log(req)
            console.log("=========")
        res.status(201).send({ "world":true })
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).send(error)
    }
})

app.use(router)

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`)
})
```

I'm not sure if I'm using `cors()` correctly, but I threw it in there to get around a pre-flight OPTIONS issue that was causing my `fetch()` to generate a failed network connection error (which didn't occur for postman).

This was my javascript fetch code:

```
const postData = {"name":"John","email":"john@john.com","password":"chocolate-raisins!!!"};


fetch("http://johnserver.com:3000/users", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
  body: postData
}).then((response)=>{
  console.log(response);
  if(!response.ok) return {}
  return response.json();
}).then((result)=>{
  console.log(result);return;
}).catch(function(error){
    alert("Post Request Error: "+error.toString());
});
```

What am I doing wrong that's causing my API to fail with `fetch()` but not with postman?

---

EDIT

The output of the `response` variable from my fetch is this:

```
Response { type: "cors", url: "http://johnserver.com:3000/users", redirected: false, status: 400, ok: false, statusText: "Bad Request", headers: Headers, body: ReadableStream, bodyUsed: false }
```

The output of the `result` variable from my fetch is this:

```
{ }
```

Comment: Can you print the `response` in your fetch result?? Also when you are calling the fetch block code??

Comment: I updated my answer with the details you requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your fetch method please do this.

Insead of `body:post Data` do --> `JSON.stringify(postData)`

And also on your then function first `return response.json()` and then 
check whatever parameters you want.

Answer (score 1):

You're not sending valid you need to stringify your object.

```
fetch("http://localhost:3000/users", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify({ "name": "John", "email": "john@john.com", "password": "chocolate-raisins!!!" })
        }).then((response) => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                return {};
            }
            return response.json();
        }).then((response) => {
            console.log(response); return;
        }).catch(function (error) {
            alert("Post Request Error: " + error.toString());
        });
```